# Stop A Button That Jumps On Hover

Tags: css, button

I have a site (http://sheisbiddy.com/the-f-word/) where the Read More link jumps when you hover your mouse over it. It only started happening when I added padding to it to make it the same size as the box below. Here's the CSS:

```
a.more-link {display:block; text-align: center; color:#e9bdd8; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:85%; position: relative; bottom: 5px;}
a.more-link:hover {background-color:white;padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;transition: color, background-color 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: color, background-color 0.1s linear; -webkit-transition: color, background-color 0.2s linear; -o-transition: color, background-color 0.1s linear;}
```

I'm using Safari if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ah geniuses! All of you! Putting the padding on the base element instead of the hover worked like a charm. I can't believe I didn't realize that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you hover, you're adding 10px of padding on the top and bottom that aren't there in the standard style.  Try removing these elements from hover

```
padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;
```

That, or you'll want to add this padding to your other style.

Answer (score 1):

You want the padding to be a part of your un`:hover`d selector. That way applying the padding only upon hovering doesn't add any size to the link.

```
a.more-link {padding 10px 0;}
```

Alternatively, since you're already using transitions you can add a padding transition to make the "jump" animated.

```
a.more-link { transition: padding 0.2s linear; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want, you could add the padding to the base class like so : 
https://jsfiddle.net/78s24fpw/

```
a.more-link { padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;display:block; text-align: center; color:#e9bdd8; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:85%; position: relative; bottom: 5px;}
a.more-link:hover {background-color:white;padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;transition: color, background-color 0.1s linear; -moz-transition:
```